# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta JPA por año y mes?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Tengo en mi base da datos PostgreSQ una fecha de tipo date así 2023-03-18 y quiero hacer una consulta JPA, para poder consultar por año mes.

Esto es algo que se me ocurre pero solo funciona en postgrest

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'yyyy-MM') FROM public.Pruebas;
```

estaba intentando esto

```
@Query("SELECT  to_char(e.id.date, 'yyyy-MM') FROM Pruebas e")
```

Quiero poder filtra todo los años y meses  ejemplo:

PostgreSQL tengo un listado de fecha algo asi

```
2023-01-01
2023-01-05
2023-02-09
2023-02-08
2023-03-13
2023-03-22
2023-03-30
```

quiero poder solo traerme con un query JPA año y el mes. si filtro por 2023-01

```
2023-01-01
2023-01-05
```

me traigo toda las que tenga relacción con el año y el mes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder filtrar por año y mes en una consulta `JPA`, puedes utilizar la función `YEAR` y `MONTH` en lugar de `to_char` de `PostgreSQL`.

Por ejemplo, si quieres filtrar todas las fechas del año y mes especificados, podrías hacer algo así:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Pruebas e WHERE YEAR(e.fecha) = :anio AND MONTH(e.fecha) = :mes")
List<Pruebas> findByAnioMes(@Param("anio") int anio, @Param("mes") int mes);
```

En este ejemplo, `fecha` es el nombre de la propiedad en la entidad `Pruebas` que representa la fecha que quieres filtrar. La consulta buscará todas las entidades `Pruebas` cuya fecha corresponda al año y mes especificados.

Para obtener todas las fechas de un año y mes determinados, simplemente llamarías al método `findByAnioMes` con los valores adecuados de `anio` y `mes`. Por ejemplo, para obtener todas las fechas del mes de enero de 2023, llamarías al método así:

```
List<Pruebas> fechasEnero = findByAnioMes(2023, 1);
```